# QWebView not rendering fonts

Tags: qt4, pyqt4, qwebview

I'm writing an application that displays static HTML files from a folder. For some reason, PyQt4's `QWebView` class isn't allowing any fonts to render, even for remote websites:

**`QWebView`**:

[image: Bad fonts, bad]

**Chrome**:

[image: Good fonts]

I'm loading the file like so:

```
self.web_view = QWebView()
self.settings = self.web_view.settings()
self.settings.setAttribute(QWebSettings.LocalContentCanAccessRemoteUrls, True)

self.web_view.load(QUrl('http://blender3d.github.com/Bevel/demo/'))
```

Are there any more security settings that I have to change in order to get this to work?

Comment: I see fonts rendered with artifacts.. what exactly do you mean by "isn't allowing any fonts to render" ?

Comment: There is only one font, and it is the only one being rendered (take a look at [Google Web Fonts](http://i.imgur.com/XISOW.png), for example). I've tried converting my fonts to different formats (TTF, WOFF, OTF, etc.), but QWebView ignores them. I've re-written my script with PyGTK and the fonts render just like Chrome, but Qt allows greater Python/JavaScript interaction.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After torturing `QWebView` for hours and hours, I finally noticed that [Font Squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator) amazingly rendered an external font. I highlighted the letters many times and sat there in awe, smiling.

Anyways, it seems like in order to make this work with `QWebView`:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Terminal Dosis';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Dosis Regular'), local('Dosis-Regular'), url('../fonts/terminal-dosis-regular.woff') format('woff');
}
```

I had to make it look like this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Terminal Dosis Regular';
  src: url('../fonts/terminal-dosis-regular.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

Note that `QWebView` doesn't like WOFF fonts. I had to convert mine to TrueType via [Font Squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator).

In short:

- Make sure your fonts are TrueType fonts.
- No `local()` stuff.
- It seems like `font-style` and `font-weight` are ignored. You have to make different font families for each style of each font (`Terminal Dosis Bold`, for example).

Comment: Another workaround for this problem: install the font-family in your system (package it in your program install). Or get the latest `QWebView` with `qtwebkit` `5.1` or later (which appears to support `.woff` fonts.

Answer (score 0):

The [stylesheet](http://blender3d.github.com/Bevel/demo/css/style.css) for the example url makes use of the css `@font-face` rule to specify online fonts.

Unfortunately, it looks like this is currently broken in QWebKit: [Bug 36351](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=36351).

Answer (score 0):

It's broken! Possible workaround in this article:

http://blog.elliottcable.name/posts/webkit_safari_3_1_and_the_css_font_face_declaration.xhtml